# Why did Scala use a while and not recursion for `find`

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Just curious why the Scala authors didn't use recursion or even pattern matching when implementing `find` on `List`s?

Their implementation looks like this:

```scala
  override final def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
    var these: List[A] = this
    while (!these.isEmpty) {
      if (p(these.head)) return Some(these.head)
      these = these.tail
    }
    None
  }
```

Using a `while` and `head` and `tail`. They could have done something for "scala-esq" with recursion no?

```scala
  @tailrec
  def find(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
    this match {
      case Nil                     => None
      case head :: tail if p(head) => Some(head)
      case elements                => find(p, elements.tail)
    }
  }
```

It can't be because of tail-call optimisation can it? Is it somehow more efficient and I'm missing it? Could it be just author preference and style?! Something inflexible about it when `A` could be anything? hmmm

Comment: Performance, the `while` implementation is a lot faster than the tail-recursive version. And the stdlib has to be very efficient. You usually do not need that level of efficiency, so you can be functional if you prefer _(I do!)_.  If you are looking at the source code for learning then let me tell you it is a bad idea, the stdlib is full of bad practices in order to be efficient.

Comment: Looking at the bytecode, I don't think there's a dramatic difference between the `while` implementation and an implementation that's tail-recursive without using pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick experiment (using Scala 2.13.2).  The three candidate implementations are:

- while-loop
- tail-recursive, but keeping the same logic as the while version
- tail-recursive with a pattern match

I've modified the logic where appropriate to depend less on compiler optimizations (`nonEmpty` vs. `!isEmpty` and explicitly saving `these.head` so it's not called twice).

```
  import scala.annotation.tailrec
  
  object ListFindComparison {
    def whileFind[A](lst: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = { 
      var these: List[A] = lst 
      while (these.nonEmpty) {
        val h = these.head

        if (p(h)) return Some(h)
        else these = these.tail
      }   
      None
    }
  
    def tailrecFind[A](lst: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = { 
      @tailrec
      def iter(these: List[A]): Option[A] =
        if (these.nonEmpty) {
          val h = these.head
          if (p(h)) Some(h)
          else iter(these.tail)
        } else None
  
      iter(lst)
    }
  
    def tailRecPM[A](lst: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = { 
      @tailrec
      def iter(these: List[A]): Option[A] =
        these match {
          case Nil => None
          case head :: tail if p(head) => Some(head)
          case _ => iter(these.tail)
        }   
  
      iter(lst)
    }
  }
```

When inspecting the bytecode (using `:javap ListFindComparison$`), we see

For `whileFind`, the emitted code is straightforward

```
Code:
   0: aload_1
   1: astore_3
   2: aload_3
   3: invokevirtual #25                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.nonEmpty:()Z
   6: ifeq          50
   9: aload_3
  10: invokevirtual #29                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.head:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  13: astore        4
  15: aload_2
  16: aload         4
  18: invokeinterface #35,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  23: invokestatic  #41                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToBoolean:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  26: ifeq          39
  29: new           #43                 // class scala/Some
  32: dup
  33: aload         4
  35: invokespecial #46                 // Method scala/Some."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  38: areturn
  39: aload_3
  40: invokevirtual #49                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.tail:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  43: checkcast     #21                 // class scala/collection/immutable/List
  46: astore_3
  47: goto          2
  50: getstatic     #54                 // Field scala/None$.MODULE$:Lscala/None$;
  53: areturn
```

The tail-recursive finds are basically the same:

```
aload_0
aload_1
aload_2
invokespecial   // call the appropriate (private) iter methods
areturn
```

The `iter` in `tailrecFind` is

```
Code:
   0: aload_1
   1: invokevirtual #25                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.nonEmpty:()Z
   4: ifeq          53
   7: aload_1
   8: invokevirtual #29                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.head:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  11: astore        4
  13: aload_2
  14: aload         4
  16: invokeinterface #35,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  21: invokestatic  #41                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToBoolean:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  24: ifeq          39
  27: new           #43                 // class scala/Some
  30: dup
  31: aload         4
  33: invokespecial #46                 // Method scala/Some."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  36: goto          50
  39: aload_1
  40: invokevirtual #49                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.tail:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  43: checkcast     #21                 // class scala/collection/immutable/List
  46: astore_1
  47: goto          0
  50: goto          56
  53: getstatic     #54                 // Field scala/None$.MODULE$:Lscala/None$;
  56: areturn
```

There's no major difference in the core of the `while` and this `iter`: it's quite likely that JIT will bring these to the same machine code after enough invocations.  `tailrecFind` has slightly greater constant overhead for getting into `iter` than `whileFind` has for getting into the loop.  There's not likely to be a meaningful performance difference here (and in fact, since `while` is leaving the language definition in dotty, the future of `while` is as a library function which tail-recursively calls a block as long as a predicate passes).

The `iter` with pattern-matching is very different:

```
Code:
   0: aload_1
   1: astore        5
   3: getstatic     #77                 // Field scala/collection/immutable/Nil$.MODULE$:Lscala/collection/immutable/Nil$;
   6: aload         5
   8: invokevirtual #80                 // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  11: ifeq          22
  14: getstatic     #54                 // Field scala/None$.MODULE$:Lscala/None$;
  17: astore        4
  19: goto          92
  22: goto          25
  25: aload         5
  27: instanceof    #82                 // class scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon
  30: ifeq          78
  33: aload         5
  35: checkcast     #82                 // class scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon
  38: astore        6
  40: aload         6
  42: invokevirtual #83                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.head:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  45: astore        7
  47: aload_2
  48: aload         7
  50: invokeinterface #35,  2           // InterfaceMethod scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  55: invokestatic  #41                 // Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToBoolean:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  58: ifeq          75
  61: new           #43                 // class scala/Some
  64: dup
  65: aload         7
  67: invokespecial #46                 // Method scala/Some."<init>":(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  70: astore        4
  72: goto          92
  75: goto          81
  78: goto          81
  81: aload_1
  82: invokevirtual #49                 // Method scala/collection/immutable/List.tail:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  85: checkcast     #21                 // class scala/collection/immutable/List
  88: astore_1
  89: goto          0
  92: aload         4
  94: areturn
```

This is unlikely to be anywhere near as performant as the versions without pattern-matching (though to be fair, the branches will in practice be *really* easy for a predictor: not-taken (not-`Nil`), not-taken (`::`), not-taken (predicate fails), except for the very last run).

It's a little interesting to me that we get a call to `equals` when checking for `Nil`: it's probably still faster than `isEmpty`/`nonEmpty`, but it would be even faster without pattern-matching and with an explicit `eq`/`ne` against `Nil`.

I also note that pattern-matching against `this` is a bit of antipattern IMO: at that point, you're almost certainly better off using virtual method dispatch since you're basically implementing a slow vtable (it does have the advantage of potentially being pre-JIT'd if you put the common case first).

If you really care about performance, I'd try to avoid pattern-matching.

PS: I haven't analyzed the simple `foldLeft` solution:

```
lst.foldLeft(None) { (acc, v) =>
  acc.orElse {
    if (p(v)) Some(v)
    else None
  }
}
```

But since that doesn't short-circuit, I suspect it won't consistently beat any of the candidates, and even in the cases where there's no match before the last element, it might not even beat the pattern-match version then.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I was curious and the question was even voted down so I was worried it wouldn't be of interest. I was academically curious and now I've got more than enough to satisfy my curiosity!